# How to choose storage class and location for Google Cloud Storage buckets

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm able to create storage buckets on Google Cloud, but I'm not able to choose the storage class {Multi-regional, Regional, Nearline, Coldline} or the location {'us-west1', etc}.

```
from google.cloud import storage    

def CreateBucket(name):
    try:
        storageClient = storage.Client()
        bucket = storageClient.create_bucket(name)
        print(f'Bucket {bucket.name} created.')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'exception!\n{ex}')


name = 'my_globally_unique_bucket_name'
CreateBucket(name)
```

The [current documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-python) does not show any parameters beyond bucket_name in Python; however, Go, Java, Node.JS, and Ruby all show parameters for the storage class and location options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the code to this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def CreateBucket(name):
        try:
            storageClient = storage.Client()
            bucket = storageClient.bucket(name)
            bucket.location = "us-west1"
            bucket.storage_class = "COLDLINE"
            bucket.create()
            print("Bucket {} created.".format(name))
        except Exception as ex:
            print("exception!\n{}".format(ex))

name = 'my_globally_unique_bucket_name'
CreateBucket(name)
```

You can find the documentation for Google Cloud Client Library for Python [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html), showing you the methods and attributes of the Class 'Bucket'.